# Некоректно срабатывает код в части функции on_data_changed. Print() срабатывает дважды,а то и трижды

Tags: python

```
import sys
import asyncio

from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, \
    QListWidget, QMessageBox, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QAbstractItemView, QMenu, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtGui

import mysql.connector as connector
import datetime


def connect():
    try:
        db = connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='123456')
        print(f"Connection to database is successful: {db}")
        return db
    except connector.Error as error:
        print(f"Something went wrong: {error}. Please, try again")


def create_database(db, database_name):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name};")
    cursor.close()


def create_tasks_table(db, database_name):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name}.tasks("
                   f"id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
                   f"title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
                   f"description TEXT NOT NULL,"
                   f"date DATETIME NOT NULL"
                   f");")
    cursor.close()


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super().__init__()

        self.left = 200
        self.top = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.width = 800
        self.title = "Task manager"

        self.db = db

        self.init_window()
        self.init_ui()
        self.show()
        self.load_tasks("SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks;")

    def on_data_changed(self, item):

        new_value = item.text()
        id = self.tasks_table.item(item.row(), 0).text()
        if item.column() == 1:
            changed_column = 'title'
        elif item.column() == 2:
            changed_column = 'description'
        else:
            changed_column = 'completed'
            new_value = 1 if item.checkState() else 0
            print(new_value)
            if new_value == 1:
                self.tasks_table.item(item.row(), 0).setBackground(QColor(102, 221, 170))
            else:
                self.tasks_table.item(item.row(), 0).setBackground(QColor(255, 255, 255))


            # color = QColor(102, 221, 170) if not new_value else QColor(255, 255, 255)

        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        query = f'UPDATE task_manager_db.tasks SET {changed_column}=\'{new_value}\' WHERE id={id};'
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
            self.db.commit()

        except connector.Error as err:
            print(err)
            cursor.close()
            exit(1)
        finally:
            # self.tasks_table.item(item.row(), 0).setBackground(QColor(55, 55, 55))
            cursor.close()

    def init_ui(self):
        root_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # title layout init
        title_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        title_label = QLabel('Title')
        self.title_error = QLabel()
        self.title_error.setStyleSheet('color:red')
        self.title_edit = QLineEdit()
        title_layout.addWidget(title_label)
        title_layout.addWidget(self.title_edit)
        title_layout.addWidget(self.title_error)

        # description layout init
        description_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        description_label = QLabel('Description')
        self.description_error = QLabel()
        self.description_error.setStyleSheet('color:red')
        self.description_edit = QLineEdit()
        description_layout.addWidget(description_label)
        description_layout.addWidget(self.description_edit)
        description_layout.addWidget(self.description_error)

        buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttons_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.sort_title_button = QPushButton('Title \u2193')
        self.sort_title_button.clicked.connect(self.sort_title)
        self.sort_description_button = QPushButton('Description \u2193')
        self.sort_description_button.clicked.connect(self.sort_description)
        self.sort_date_button = QPushButton('Date \u2193')
        self.sort_date_button.clicked.connect(self.sort_date)
        add_task_button = QPushButton('Add task')
        add_task_button.clicked.connect(self.add_task)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.sort_title_button)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.sort_description_button)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(self.sort_date_button)
        buttons_layout.addWidget(add_task_button)

        # self.tasks_list = QListWidget()
        self.tasks_table = QTableWidget()
        # self.tasks_table.itemChanged.connect(self.on_data_changed)
        self.tasks_table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tasks_table.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.tasks_table.setColumnCount(5)
        # self.tasks_table.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)
        # self.tasks_table.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.change_item)

        # self.tasks_table.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.double_clicked_item)
        # self.tasks_table.itemPressed.connect(self.entered_item)
        self.tasks_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['id', 'title', 'description', 'date', 'completed'])
        self.tasks_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tasks_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tasks_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tasks_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tasks_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.no_tasks_table = QLabel('No tasks in table')
        self.no_tasks_table.hide()

        delete_button = QPushButton('Delete row')
        delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_row)
        root_layout.addLayout(title_layout)
        root_layout.addLayout(description_layout)
        root_layout.addLayout(buttons_layout)
        # root_layout.addWidget(self.tasks_list)
        root_layout.addWidget(self.tasks_table)
        root_layout.addWidget(self.no_tasks_table)
        root_layout.addWidget(delete_button)
        self.setLayout(root_layout)

    def change_item(self):
        pass

    # def double_clicked_item(self, item):
    #     new_value = item.text()
    #     print(new_value)

    def sort_date(self):
        self.tasks_table.setRowCount(0)
        if self.sort_date_button.text() == 'Date \u2193':
            query = 'SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY date ASC;'
            self.load_tasks(query)
            self.sort_date_button.setText('Date \u2191')
        else:
            query = 'SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY date DESC;'
            self.load_tasks(query)
            self.sort_date_button.setText('Date \u2193')

    def sort_description(self):
        self.tasks_table.setRowCount(0)
        if self.sort_description_button.text() == 'Description \u2193':
            query = 'SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY description ASC;'
            self.load_tasks(query)
            self.sort_description_button.setText('Description \u2191')
        else:
            query = 'SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY description DESC;'
            self.load_tasks(query)
            self.sort_description_button.setText('Description \u2193')

    def sort_title(self):
        self.tasks_table.setRowCount(0)
        if self.sort_title_button.text() == 'Title \u2193':
            query = "SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY title ASC;"
            self.load_tasks(query)
            self.sort_title_button.setText('Title \u2191')
        else:
            query = "SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY title DESC;"
            self.load_tasks(query)
            self.sort_title_button.setText('Title \u2193')

    def delete_row(self):
        if self.tasks_table.selectedItems():
            cursor = self.db.cursor()
            id = int(self.tasks_table.selectedItems()[0].text())
            query = "DELETE FROM task_manager_db.tasks WHERE id=%s;"
            try:
                cursor.execute(query, (id,))
                self.db.commit()
                self.tasks_table.removeRow(self.tasks_table.currentRow())
                if not self.tasks_table.rowCount():
                    self.tasks_table.hide()
                    self.no_tasks_table.show()
                cursor.close()
            except connector.Error as error:
                print(error)
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

    def itemChanged(self):
        pass

    def load_tasks(self, query):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        tasks = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(tasks) > 0:
            self.tasks_table.show()
            self.no_tasks_table.hide()
            for id, title, description, date, completed in tasks:
                row_position = self.tasks_table.rowCount()
                self.tasks_table.insertRow(row_position)
                idItem = QTableWidgetItem()
                idItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
                idItem.setText(str(id))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 0, idItem)
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(title))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 2, QTableWidgetItem(description))
                dateItem = QTableWidgetItem()
                dateItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
                dateItem.setText(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 3, dateItem)

                completed_check_box = QTableWidgetItem()
                completed_check_box.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                completed_check_box.setCheckState(Qt.Checked if completed else Qt.Unchecked)
                completed_check_box.setData(Qt.UserRole, completed_check_box.checkState())
                if completed:
                    for index in range(0, 4):
                        self.tasks_table.item(row_position, index).setBackground(QColor(102, 221, 170))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 4, completed_check_box)

        else:
            self.tasks_table.hide()
            self.no_tasks_table.show()
        cursor.close()
        self.tasks_table.itemChanged.connect(self.on_data_changed)

    def init_window(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

    def add_task(self):
        self.title_error.clear()
        self.description_error.clear()

        title = self.title_edit.text()
        description = self.description_edit.text()

        has_error = False

        if not title:
            has_error = True
            self.title_error.setText('Enter the title')

        if not description:
            has_error = True
            self.description_error.setText('Enter the description')

        if not has_error:
            cursor = self.db.cursor()
            query = "INSERT INTO task_manager_db.tasks(title, description, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
            values = (title, description, datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            cursor.execute(query, values)
            db.commit()
            if cursor.rowcount:
                message = QMessageBox()
                message.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
                message.setText("Task has been added successfully")
                message.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
                message.buttonClicked.connect(self.on_ok_click)
                message.exec_()
                # title (description) date
                # self.tasks_list.addItem(f'{title}({description})')j
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM task_manager_db.tasks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
                data = cursor.fetchall()[0]
                print(data)
                row_position = self.tasks_table.rowCount()
                self.tasks_table.insertRow(row_position)
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(data[0])))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(data[1]))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 2, QTableWidgetItem(data[2]))
                dateItem = QTableWidgetItem()
                dateItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
                dateItem.setText(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 3, dateItem)
                completed_check_box = QTableWidgetItem()
                completed_check_box.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                completed_check_box.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
                completed_check_box.setData(Qt.UserRole, completed_check_box.checkState())
                self.tasks_table.setItem(row_position, 4, completed_check_box)
            cursor.close()

    def on_ok_click(self):
        self.tasks_table.show()
        self.no_tasks_table.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = connect()
    create_database(db, "task_manager_db")
    create_tasks_table(db, "task_manager_db")

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(db)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Почему у вас строка `self.tasks_table.itemChanged.connect(self.on_data_changed)` 
находится в методе `def load_tasks(self, query):`, а не после строки `self.tasks_table = QTableWidget()`? 
И с именами будьте аккуратнее, например методу `def itemChanged(self):` 
я бы дал другое название.

Comment: Если я буду вызывать ее в init_ui то в функции on_data_changed, print() будет возвращать все данные из таблицы. А мне нужно только выбранное.